# How to change position of label according to my example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, position, uilabel

Check below image,

[image]

the label “No Records” is showing.

I want to change its position i.e I want to move to little bit up so when uitableview load it will hide.

When I was created project, that time it was working fine. After I added new view (new navigation ) for sorting and filter then label position changed to down and now it is not hiding behind loader.

Code written for this is,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    NSInteger numOfSections = 0;
    if ([_mutableArray count]==0)
    {
        UILabel *noDataLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height)];
        noDataLabel.text             =  NSLocalizedString(@"No Records..!!!",nil);
        noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
        noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    }
    else
    {
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        numOfSections                = 1;
        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }

    return numOfSections;

}
```

is there way to adjust the label according to our choice ??

Comment: It's simpler to just hide the label when the loading is present.

Comment: Don't set the data source, or call reload data until you have fetched the data.

Answer (score 0):

Change y position of you noDataLabel as in below code i have add 75 check below code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    NSInteger numOfSections = 0;
    if ([_mutableArray count]==0)
    {
        UILabel *noDataLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 75, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height)];
        noDataLabel.text             =  NSLocalizedString(@"No Records..!!!",nil);
        noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
        noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    }
    else
    {
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        numOfSections                = 1;
        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }

    return numOfSections;

}
```

you can change y position as per your convince.

you can also set in minus(-75) if you want to display you label above loading indicator.

[image]

Comment: I changed the position i.e set y=75 or -75, it is not changing the position

Comment: @NikitaPatil do you want to change label position?

Comment: Ha. I want to change the position of label. Its current position is center of tableview. I want to change little bit up.

Comment: I added that label programmatically to show "No Records" found in such scenario that, when there will be no data in my table view then it will show that label. If data is there, it will show. But now what is happening is when data is comming from json data, loader is loading as well as that label is displaying in background for some few sec while displaying details in table view. This is happeing

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *noDataLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height)];
```

this means that your label's size is equal to tableView size, so to up your label, you can manipulate with this code

```
CGRectMake(0, -10, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height) //example, this will move label
```

but such kind of solutions are not recommended, just try to hide label when loading, and show when done.

Comment: your first point is right and the code you modified i.e you changed position if y=-10. It is not changing its position. Still it is displaying same position

Comment: I added that label programmatically to show "No Records" found in such scenario that, when there will be no data in my table view then it will show that label. If data is there, it will show. But now what is happening is when data is comming from json data, loader is loading as well as that label is displaying in background for some few sec while displaying details in table view. This is happeing.

Comment: Sorry for late response, please try to set 
CGRectMake(0, -10, tableView.bounds.size.width, 50) 
and say did it moved ? I think its actulally huge height may cause problem ...